# How to add new key/value pair element to an existing array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular-directive

```
var onHomePageLoaded = function(retMsg)
 {
  $scope.data = retMsg.data.records;
  $scope.data.link : 'http://www.newwebsite.com'

 }
```

After i have added link element (key/value) to the javascript object, i am not able to get the same in the HTML template

```
<div ng-repeat="record in data">

  <a ng-href="{{record.link}}"> Click Here </a>

</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean? Array or object? What is the problem?

Comment: Kindly update your question, how are you using it. Show some code.

Comment: You have different names?!? `report`or `record`?

Comment: it is record.link. sorry it was an typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript is a dynamic language. You can add properties to existing objects in a very simple way , like  assigning a value to an existing property. Just add a new property

```
$scope.data.link = 'http://www.newwebsite.com'
```

if `retMsg.data.records` is an array, still you can add a property to `$scope.data`.

if you want different link for every object in array then, do this.

```
$scope.data.forEach(function(obj){
    obj.link = "your custom link" // write your logic here to produce different link.
});
```

Comment: But i am not able to access the link in my HTML if i use ng-repeat and access like data.link?

Comment: Dou you want the same link for every object or a different for every item

Comment: i want the different link for each object. @ZohaibIjaz, i have updated my html template.

Comment: How will be link generated?? because you want different for all objects.

Comment: i have an api which will gives me the random link for each item.

Comment: Ok , then append that link to each object as I did above.

Answer (score 0):

If data is an array you can use

```
$scope.data.push(yourData);
```

for example

```
$scope.data.push({link : 'http://www.newwebsite.com'});
```

Or if you want to access the objects inside the array and add them a key value pair you can do as follow:

```
// add the link to the first entry
$scope.data[0].link = 'http://www.newwebsite.com';
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry. Do not know if I understood well.

Maybe you can define scope.data as:

```
$scope.data = {retMsg.data.records}
```

Then for example a function:

```
    $scope.addNew = funtion(){
     $scope.data.newElement = $scope.viewElement
    };
```

In your HTML

```
  <label>{{data}}</label> // Which makes reference to the $scope.data at the controller 
  <input ng-change="addNew()" ng-model="viewElement"></input>
  <label>{{data.newElement}} // Will be empty at the very beginning but will show the new element once it is created.
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I see several issues with your code.

First, you use the variable name `record` in your `ng-repeat`, but then use `report` in `ng-href`. I assume those should be the same.

Also, `link` isn't a member of `record`, it is a member of `data`. You set it as a member of `data` here: `$scope.data.link : 'http://www.newwebsite.com'`. If you want to add that link to each `record`, in your `onHomePageLoaded` function, you'll need to loop through all the records you add to `data`, and add the `link` property to each one.